# Using tf.split or tf.slice for keras layers

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, keras

I want to split my training samples of size `[batchSize, 2, 16]` into 16 tensors of size `[batchSize, 2]` and input them to the same model. How can I accomplish them in keras?

I have first implemented this in following way,

```
def functionA(x_Config):

    y = layers.Input(shape=(2,16,))

    hidden1 = 5
    hidden2 = 10

    x_input = layers.Input(shape=(2,))
    hidden_layer1 = Dense(hidden1, activation='relu')(x_input)
    hidden_layer2 = Dense(hidden2, activation='relu')(hidden_layer1)
    x_output = Dense(x_Config.m, activation='linear')(hidden_layer2)
    model_x= Model(inputs=x_input, outputs=x_output)


    for i in range(16):
        x_input = Lambda(lambda x: x[:, :, i])(y)

        if i == 0:
           x_output = model_x(x_input)
        else:
            x_output = layers.concatenate([x_output, 
                                      model_x(x_input)])

    x_output = Lambda(lambda x: x[:, :tf.cast(N, tf.int32)])(x_output)

    final_model = Model(y, x_output)

    return final_model
```

PS: I have a trained model for the same NN architecture for `model_x` for `[batchSize, 2]` inputs (without the need for splitting). This model performs very well. When I tried to load the weights of that model to above mentioned code, `model_x`, it does not give good performance at all and does not train well.

So I believe my problems lies inside the loop in the Lamda layer. How can I use `tf.split` or `tf.slice` for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use [`tf.unstack`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/unstack) function:

```
tensors = tf.unstack(data, axis=2)
```